# Правильно ли записаны уравнения?

Tags: c#

**Уравнения которые нужно записать:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**c# код:**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите число");
            String s = Console.ReadLine();
            double a = Convert.ToDouble(s);

            double z1 = ( Math.Sin(2 * a) + Math.Sin(5 * a) - Math.Sin(3 * a) ) / ( Math.Cos(a) - Math.Cos(3 * a) + Math.Cos(5 * a) );

            double z2 = Math.Tan(3*a);


            Console.WriteLine(z1);
            Console.WriteLine(z2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В чём сомнения? Пробовали скомпилировать программу (компилируется?), подставлять разные числа и сверяиь значения? Ну вот подставить ноль на входе - что должно быть на выходе?

Comment: @A K значения z1 и z2 должны сойтись, а они не сходятся

Comment: А вы уверены, что они должны сойтись? Судя даже по графикам этих двух функций: они разные. Можете в том же WolframAlpha на это посмотреть или вручную возьмите и подсчитайте на калькуляторе. Например, при `a = 0.2` у меня выходит `z1 = 0.95`, а `z2 = 0.68`. А если по коду: тут ошибок никаких нет, вы верно записали уравнения.